# Print output for text pattern match

Tags: regex, perl, printing

New to Perl and my limitations are frustrating. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Creating script which will:

1. Input a file and parse for test pattern match
2. Output the specific matched word to a variable
3. Run external windows program (nslookup) against the variable,
4. Parse output of nslookup for test pattern match
5. Output the specific matched word to a variable
6. Perform a substitution between the two variables
7. And then output the modified text into a file

echoing "This is a Machine: ford.com test" into the input.txt file

I"m doing something wrong with the printout because I keep receiving the following

> Useless use of string in void context at test21.pl line 38.
>   Non-authoritative answer: Use of uninitialized value $_ in print at
>   test21.pl line 39.

0

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Nslookup;
use File::Copy;

sub host {
    my $result;
    my $node = shift;
    print system("nslookup $node.com | findstr ^Name: >> POOH");
    open( my $stuff, "<", "POOH" ) || die "Can't open input.txt: $!";
    while (<$stuff>) {
        if (/(Name:)(\s+)(\w+)/) {
            $result = $3;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

my $captured;
my $captured2;
my $jeff;
my $in   = 'input.txt';
my $out  = 'output.txt';
my $test = 'test.txt';

copy( $in, $out ) || die "File cannot be copied.";
open OUTPUT, "< $out"  || die "Can't open input.txt: $!";
open TEST,   "> $test" || die "Can't open input.txt: $!";

while (<OUTPUT>) {    # assigns each line in turn to $_
    if (/(Machine:)(\s)(\w+)/) {
        $captured = $3;
        $jeff     = host($captured);
    }

    "s/$captured/$jeff/g";
    print TEST;

}
```

Comment: I don't know a lot about Perl, but the problem seems to be the second to last line. What if you just remove the quotes around the substitution operator?

Comment: I think m.buettner is correct. On line 38, it should be something like `s/$captured/$jeff/g;`. When you put the quotes on it, you're making a string. It says you are using it in void context because you aren't doing anything with the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes around "s/$captured/$jeff/g". For second issue, I would be more explicit about what I print to file handler. e.g. print TEST $_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your recommendations. Located some code which directed me to save the default scalar variable, after inputting a line of code using the while loop, into a variable. Doing so save me a lot of messy coding. Here's the functioning code.

```
#!E:/Perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub host {
    my $result;
    my $node = shift;
    print system("nslookup $node.com | findstr ^Name: >> LOOKUP");
    open(my $stuff,  "<",  "LOOKUP") || die "Can't open input.txt: $!"; 
    while (<$stuff>) { 
       if ( /(Name:)(\s+)(\w+)/ ) {
       $result = $3;
       }
   }
   return $result;
}

my $captured;
my $jeff;


open INPUT, '<', 'input.txt' || die "Can't open input.txt: $!";
open OUTPUT, '>', 'output.txt' || die "Can't open input.txt: $!";

while (<INPUT>) {     # while loop inputs each line of input.txt file
  my($line) = $_; 
  if ( /(Machine:)(\s)(\w+)/ ){ 
  $captured = $3; 
  $jeff = host($captured); 
  $_ = $line; 
  $line =~ s/$captured/$jeff/g; 
  print OUTPUT $line; 
  }
}

close OUTPUT;
close INPUT;
```